# How to store ion range slider POSITION in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I am able to get the values for the slider as the user scrolls as well as where the slider finishes (The end position of the slider). I am able to store both of these values in localstorage however I am unable to get the slider position to be fixed and reflected on refresh; it resets every time.

I've checked the documentation about this but can't find anything about the slider state persisting. In my codepen below you can see that I am storing the value of the slider as it moves as well as its finished position in two input feels. They persist on refresh with local storage.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLovRV?editors=1011

Function for storing slider end position:

```
var sliderEndPosition = function(){
 $pv.prop("value", finishValue);
 localStorage.setItem( 'SliderEndPosition', finishValue);
}; 

(function () { 
 from = 0;
 $pv.prop("value", 0);
 if (localStorage.getItem("SliderEndPosition"))  {
 $pv.prop("value", localStorage.getItem("SliderEndPosition"));
 from = $pv.prop;
 }
  })();
```

Is there a way I can connect the stored value to reflect the position of the slider permanently even after refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. In ion slider you get the final value with the OnUpdate callback. I was able to take this value and store it to a variable. Then in the configuration of the slider I specified the from value (this is where the slider ends) to equal the variable. So whenever the slider ends, this variable gets updated and changed in the ion slider settings as well as persists after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the "from" property of the config object needs to be a string or a number. instead, it gets Jquery dom object.

change it, like so: `from: localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes"),`

Comment: Would that be in the if statement? I tried it like this and was not successful:

    (function () { 
    from = 0;
    $pv.prop("value", 0);
    if (from: localStorage.getItem("SliderEndPosition"))  {
     $pv.prop("value", localStorage.getItem("SliderEndPosition"));
     from = $pv.prop;
     }
})();

Comment: no need. I'm pretty sure nothing will happen if "StoreMinutes" in localStorage does not exist.

Comment: in any case, you can do something like this: 
`from: localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes") || 0`.
this way, if StoreMinutes returns `undefined`, 0 will be used instead

Comment: Sorry  maybe I wasn't clear with my initial explanation. The storeminutes is a different value from the slider which I am storing. This is the value that updates everytime the user scrolls, which I have no issue with and am not focused on at the moment.

The value I am struggling with is the SliderEndPosition which is the final position/value of the slider when the user lets go. This value from what I've seen in the documentation is connected to the slider position. I want this position to be maintained even when the browser is refreshed.

Hope that's more clear :)